# Change glyphicon color on text change in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have following code snippet :

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TagName, new {@class = "textBoxTextFormat", @id = "newTagText"})
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3" >
    <a href="#" id="addNewTagButton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" style="color: #4790b8; vertical-align: bottom; margin-top: 5px; font-size: 30px;"></span></a>
    <a href="#" id="cancelNewTagButton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" style="color: #4790b8; vertical-align: bottom; margin-top: 5px; font-size: 30px;"></span></a>
</div>
```

which produces following output:
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZphRW.png)

I want to make save and cancel button go darker when text changes in the text box.I tried following but it does not work:

```
$(document).on('change', '#newTagText', function (e) {
    $('#addNewTagButton').css('color', '#0000FF');
});
```

Please help me here.

Comment: I could change the color but to make it happen I have to click out side the text box:                                                                                                  $(document).on("change", "#newTagText", function (e) {
        $(".glyphicon-floppy-disk").css("color", "#0000FF");
    });

Answer (score 0):

```
Pass the text field event to this.

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.clickable').on("click", function(){
    $(this).find('.glyphicon').css("color", "#FFF000");
});
});
```

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/T9Dk9/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change span color

```
$(document).on("change", "#newTagText", function (e) {
    $("#addNewTagButton span").css("color", "#0000FF");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could do that: Instead of 'change' , 'keyup' worked !

```
  $(document).on("keyup", "#newTagText", function (e) {
        $(".glyphicon-floppy-disk").css("color", "#0000FF");
        $(".glyphicon-remove-circle").css("color", "#0000FF");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#newTagText").on('change', function () {
    $('#addNewTagButton').css('color', '#0000FF !important');
});
```